# How to tell which page a user was on when they fired the first of an event type in Google Analytics

Tags: events, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to see what page on the site my users were on when they fired the first event action: add to cart, effectively starting their shopping journey within that session. I'm in Google Analytics, but completely stumped how to combine the pageviews and event action to pinpoint that this was the page the user was on the first time the user fired that event in their session (assuming Unique Event could be a metric used?).

Would love some ideas and help! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `Events` report you can't deduce when a user clicked for the first time on an element. The data is aggregated.

You could do it for example by sending a custom dimension at the time of the click on your element and assigning a cookie that checks if that information has already been sent to Analytics. If the cookie exists, don't send that dimension anymore.

It is not a 100% reliable method but it allows you to get the information you want for the future.